# How can I get old MC Server versions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a frequent Minecraft player and I'd like to create a 1.3.2 Minecraft server as a tribute to the old days, but I'm not sure where to find a 1.3.2 version. I tried mcversions.com, but you have to pay money to have a server through there, which is not what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MCVersions doesn't require you to have a server; it's an option, but you can download the JAR from their website instead. They link to the existing Mojang download links. Be sure to click precisely (the button is pretty small, with the "host through us" button right below it).

Here's the 1.3.2 link [from Mojang itself](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.3.2/minecraft_server.1.3.2.jar).

Answer (score 0):

I use Aternos.org for free servers, but there's this drawback that some wait time is required to start the server.

They also provide older versions of minecraft(even latest snapshot). You can also add modpacks and other plugins.

[image: Aternos.org supports all versions]

Answer (score -1):

Step by Step:

1. Open minecraft launcher
2. Click the "New profile" button
   [image]
   Yeah the one in the bottom left
3. Name Your Profile
   [image]

4.
You don t have to mess with anything else expect of the version and if you are not sure it can be easily undone

5.
[image]
Use the dropdown menu to choose the version and the windows to specify stuff about the version.

Enjoy minecrafting.

I actually have to thank you because I learned a lot of new stuff about the new windows 10 photo editing app. Thanks to you.

Comment: This is not what he was looking for, he wants a 1.3.2 server, not a client.

Comment: oh srry I didn t realize just got overexcited over the reputation

Comment: It's fine haha, I know the feeling.

Comment: lol but don t talk to me like this theese are comments not chat. but thnx